# Using cross_val_predict for predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following code where I want to use `k-fold cross validation` for a Linear Regression model:

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=100)
predi = cross_val_predict(model, train[columns], train[target], cv = kf)
predi = pandas.Series(predi)

model.fit(data[columns], data[target])
pred_test = model.predict(test[columns])
print(mean_squared_error(pred_test, test[target]))
```

However, I am not sure whether the code does what I would like it to do. Specifically, I am not sure about the `model.fit` part. Does it even use the cross-validation?

The reason why I am not sure that calculating it like this yields worse results than without cross-validation.

Answer (score 0):

No. CV is just for checking the performance of model on a data (or rather different parts of it)

When you call `fit()`, it will fit the whole data supplied at the time whereas cross-validation only uses parts of the data (leaving 1 fold in each iteration). So this data difference may cause the estimator to perform better or worse.

Comment: @Quasar The correct expression is what you are doing in your code. The model should be fitted on whole of data. Now why it gives bad results is upon you to inspect. Maybe the data in folds of cross-validation is imbalanced and may appear to give you good results. Maybe the actual data is imbalanced, which was not in cv folds.

Comment: Does this mean that cross_val_predict store its findings in the model and these are used when I fit the data in the 4th line?

Comment: @Quasar No. Cross-validation is for you. Model will not use that. Cv is for you to analyse the effect of different data on your model. Check and change the parameters of model or modify the data so that it can handle such data and then fit on whole data.

Answer (score 0):

model.fit doesn't have any functionality to divide the data. It just works on the cost function minimization problem and creates a model (means find parameters).

Also if you think that you create a loop and you divide the data on every iteration and call model.fit again and again you get the more generalized model, then it's not possible because on calling fit 2nd time on linear regression model object, it forgets about old data.